# Reinstalling Windows/Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin - Cannot find Android SDK

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sdk-tools

After reinstalling Windows/Visual Studio 2015/Xamarin I can no longer compile Android projects as Xamarin cannot locate the Android SDK.

I installed the Android SDK via the Xamarin installer to the default path (AppData) and as you can see from the screenshot the path is configured correctly.

[image: Xamarin- Android SDK path settings]

When I run a build I get the following error as the Android SDK path Xamarin is searching for is in `Program Files (x86)` despite the `Android SDK location` setting pointing to AppData.

> No Android platform found. Please click here to open the SDK Manager and install an Android SDK Platform.

How can I configure Xamarin to use the Android SDK in AppData?

Additional info:

*`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools\Path` is also pointing to AppData*

*I dont think its relevant but I used the Windows 10 reset & keep files feature to reinstall, perhaps it left some residual configuration that is conflicting with the new installation...*

Comment: Maybe you could just reinstall it from the Google page. It happened to me once.

Comment: can you confirm you have android API level 25 in the android-sdk path. i.e. android-sdk\platforms\android-25? I know there is a program files x86 error but please check android-25 folder is in your specified sdk path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Confirm you have correct android api level installed. In your case android API level 25. Copy your exact android-sdk path from Xamarin settings into explorer address. and then navigate into the platforms subfolder from there to ensure it is installed in that exact location e.g. android-sdk\platforms\android-25? I know there is a program files x86 error but please check android-25 folder is in your specified sdk path.
2. Try run xdecleanup.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE
3. (I know you have tried this but for answer robustness sake) Ensure HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tool points to the correct sdk location
4. restart your pc and try a clean rebuild

Comment: You are correct I did not have 25. I was aware that I had `25.0.1` & `25.0.2` & wrongly assumed minor revisions were backward compatible. After installing v25 through the SDK manager the project compiles despite not having any SDK versions in the directory shown in the error. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should point your environment variable to the location of sdk in AppData->Local->Android->android-sdk, 
and update all your android sdk tools and android sdk platform tools in sdk manager.