# Existing Visual Studio 2015 with Existing Android SDK configuration

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, mobile, installation

I successfully:

1. **already installed Android Studio v3**
2. **already have VStudio 2015 enterprise Upd.2**
3. **already used Android SDK as shown in the picture below**

[image: Android SDK]

But then, I **need to explore C# for the mobile development using Vstudio 2015 Enterprise**.

My questions are:

1. Since VStudio 2015 includes the additional installation of Android SDK, wouldn't it
   be too much duplicates of SDK(s)?
2. How to configure VStudio 2015 with my existing Android SDK? Without any redundancy SDK(s), etc....
3. Can i disable the Third-Party installation (seems it's overwhelming).

[image: size of vstudio with mobile development]

Comment: Maybe you can try go `Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings` to change the location of your Android SDK, configure the settings there to make sure the path is where your Android SDK from Android Studio is. More details see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/android-sdk-location?tabs=windows).

Comment: And if you encounter one situation that VS can't recognize your Android SDK downloaded by Android Studio, you may get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737510/reinstalling-windows-visual-studio-2015-xamarin-cannot-find-android-sdk). But as we can see, those links are for VS, I'm not sure if it works perfectly for your situation since I have no Android Studio in my machine to test it... Anyway, hope it makes some help :)

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can the setting in my comments help to resolve it?

Comment: thanks @LanceLi-MSFT,... but inside Toosl | Options | i found no Xamarin.

Seems i need to install it full.
but it cost me alot (24 gb more) from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-install-the-xamarin-in-visual-studio-2015/

i dont want to include the Third-Party as well... as I already mentioned, I already have the Android SDK installed, but not from VStudio. I just want to try C# mobile development without re-installing (duplicates) of android SDK etc...